# In selenium is it possible to give Common path for all capture screenshots

Tags: selenium, phpunit

Hi is it possible to give some common path for the captureEntirePageScreenshot, I am creating a test suit using selenium and phpunit which will execute all the selenium test cases from the particular folder, but if user has given some different path for captureEntirePageScreenshot function in any testcase I wanted to override that path.

Please let me know if anybody has did this before,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had solved this issue,

I have to set this path in drivers.php file of selenium, and it will override users input parameters.